# Atomic transaction for multiple different API calls SOAP

Tags: c#, transactions

I'm a little lost at the moment.  I am writing a payment page and when the customer clicks "Make Payment" I have an ajax call that

1. Adds the information to an MSSQL database
2. Adds the information to a third party system using an API
3. Makes the payment (this could also fail for various reasons such as wrong card number etc)
4. Sends confirmation emails.

   var workResult = AddWorkRequest(model);
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(workResult))
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, workResult);
   }

   var orderResult = AddToDatabase(model, workResult);
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderResult))
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, orderResult);
   }

   var paymentResult = MakePayment(model);
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paymentResult))
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.PaymentRequired, paymentResult);
   }

   var emailResult = SendConfirmationEmails(model, orderResult);
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailResult))
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, emailResult);
   }

My issue is any one of the 4 steps could cause the process to fail, but I really need an atomic transaction around them all.

Comment: It isn't possible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensating_transaction is likely your best option.

Comment: 25 seconds.......impressive.  Thanks for the feedback mjwills